# Error when using CreaPrim addon

Tags: scripting, add-on

I installed the [CreaPrim](http://www.ewocprojects.be/object_creaprim.py) addon and when I try to add a new primitive, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/CreaPrim - create your own primitives", line 141, in invoke
 NameError: global name 'do_creaprim' is not defined
 location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: for what version of blender was this add on written for?

Comment: @Vader according to its bl_info for version 2.64

Comment: @stacker I think the API has changed since, breaking the old code.

Comment: @Vader In line 141 there is a invocation of a function which is defined in line 208. Can't test this at the moment.

Comment: @stacker I can't test it either atm. But what you described is a problem.

Comment: @stacker Thanks for taking a look at the code...the original developers of the script don't seem to be around anymore. This script isn't such a big deal to me, so don't trouble yourself over fixing it, just if it's super easy to do. Not being a coder, I have no idea how easy or hard this would be to fix.

Comment: I posted this question in BlenderArists: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?332531-CreaPrim-script-giving-errors-when-used-in-2-70&p=2616221#post2616221

Answer (score 1):

Just so this is said... this is a bug, meant for the developer of the addon to fix... I would file a bug report.

ie: **There most likely is no way to fix it without re coding the addon**.

community answer on bug reports here:

[Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

**EDIT**

If the addon was working in a older version, then one solution would be to roll back to a previous version. Its a bit drastic but if you want to use the addon badly enough it would probably fix it.